# Ratio of the derivative of a function to the function

Tags: derivatives

If we know that $f(x) = \frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}$ and $f(x) = \frac{2x}{2+x^2}$, can we simply say that $g(x) = k(2+x^2)$ for some constant $k$?

Comment: Do you mean $f(x)=\frac {2x}{2+x^2}$?  As you have written it, $f(x)$ is a constant

Comment: Aren't you mixing the letters $\;a,\,x\;$ ?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for reminding